# How to alias 'git' to 'g' so that bash-completion rules are preserved?

Tags: command-line, bash, git, auto-completion

If I do this:

```
alias g='git'
```

I loose all completion rules (i.e. branches and remotes are no longer being automatically completed when I hit TAB after typing, for example `g push o`).

Comment: While I don't have an answer for you, I'm going to have to take a minute and wonder if not typing those two other letters is really giving you much of an advantage?

Comment: Sure it does! I'm typing 'g' probably over a 100 times a day.

Comment: Aliasing often-used short commands to even shorter aliases saves me hundreds of keypresses a day. According to my shell history, I have used the alias `g=git` 756 times in the past month, meaning I saved pressing the 'g' and 'i' keys 1512 times total.

That, combined with my git aliases, probably saves me tens of thousands of key presses a month.

Comment: The main point of shortening keystrokes is helping your hands keep up with your brain.

Comment: The script at http://superuser.com/questions/436314/how-can-i-get-bash-to-perform-tab-completion-for-my-aliases worked so well I think it deserves a mention.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Copying and modifying opportunely from `/etc/bash_completion.d/git`, add the following lines to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F _git g 2>/dev/null \
    || complete -o default -o nospace -F _git g
```

Comment: Ha! Wunderbar! Works just like it should :)

Comment: I also had to add `source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git` to my .bashrc

Comment: Not sure if the `.bashrc` code here works, but this answer is definitely out of date. `/etc/bash_completion.d/git` doesn't seem to exist on 14.04. See [lzap's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/642778/219582) below.

Answer (score 36):

Latest bash-completion upstream moved and renamed things a bit. It's now:

```
source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git
__git_complete g __git_main
```

Use this in recent versions of Ubuntu (e.g. 14.04, also Fedora 22+) when you encounter:

```
completion: function `_git' not found
```

during completing.

Comment: Seems like this is the only correct answer here.

Comment: Use `__git_complete gc _git_checkout` (or similar) to set up completions for more specific aliases. Search `/usr/.../git` as above to find the right name.

Comment: @MaxWallace - when you set the aliases for particular git methods in .gitconfig (e.g. gc = checkout), there is no need to explicitly configure completion for them.

Comment: @PiotrAleksanderChmielowski Thanks! But I don't think that works for top-level bash aliases (e.g. `gc` => `git checkout`) as opposed to aliasing `c` to `checkout` within `git`, and saying `git c`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @MaxWallace Yes, you are right, my mistake ;)

Comment: this works with Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 9):

In `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias g='git'
source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git
complete -o default -o nospace -F _git g
```

Via http://29a.ch/2013/8/9/fixing-bash-autocomplete-on-ubuntu-13-04

Comment: I upvoted this in 2015, but it no longer works for me on Ubuntu 22.04 with git 2.34.1. I still like `alias g='git'`, but I use [Izap's answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/642778/25773) for the bash completion.

Answer (score 4):

First, look up the original completion command. Example:

```
$ complete | grep git

complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F __git_wrap__git_main git
```

Now add these to your startup script (e.g. ~/.bashrc):

```
# copy the original statement, but replace the last command (git) with your alias (g)
complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F __git_wrap__git_main g

# load dynamically loaded completion functions (may not be required)
_completion_loader git
```

The `_completion_loader` line may not be required. But for some situations, the completion function is only loaded dynamically after you type the command and press `TAB` the first time. So if you haven't used the original command, and try the alias + `TAB`, you may get an error like "bash: completion: function not found".

Comment: Works great.  For me this is the correct answer, the grep command on complete is handy.  Did not need the completion loader.

Answer (score 1):

The [updated way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15009611/292408) (complete wouldn't work for me):

1. `cd` - switch to your home directory
2. `wget https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash`
3. Add `source ~/git-completion.bash` to your .bashrc file (if you don't have this file make one in your home folder, bash will look for it automatically)
4. Add `alias g='git'`to your .bashrc file.
5. Start a new session or source your changes with `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: You skipped the part where they actually added completion in the comment you linked to: `__git_complete g _git`

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness, I'd like to add an answer using the `~/.bash-completion` file, which gets sourced at the end of the bash-completion script:

```
_xfunc git __git_complete g __git_main
_xfunc git __git_complete gl _git_log
_xfunc git __git_complete gd _git_diff
_xfunc git __git_complete gb _git_branch
```

Then in my `~/.bashrc` I have just the aliases. I was trying to:

- avoid poluting my `~/.bashrc` with bash-completion stuff (keep stuff where it belongs) ✓
- avoid sourcing the whole git-completion into my shell ☹

Unforutnately the `_xfunc` sources the git-completion  anyway. I'll update this answer once I figure out how to do it properly (I also asked on lunchpad [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/bash-completion/+question/286885)).

Answer (score -1):

Look at here: https://gist.github.com/scue/576310b7c6b7714aad05

```
wget https://gist.github.com/scue/576310b7c6b7714aad05/raw/459d46761c231f5c373c1cf496920b01bb6669d2/.bash_aliases.git -O ~/.bash_aliases.git
echo "test -e ~/.bash_aliases.git && source ~/.bash_aliases.git" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Enjoy!(^o^)/

Comment: Sorry, but that's something completely different. Making such simple alias es for whole commands is trivial.

Comment: I just make them work like git plugin of Oh-My-Zsh: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh

Answer (score -1):

You may just define aliases as usual:

```
alias g='git'
```

Then install [complete-alias](https://github.com/cykerway/complete-alias) to make bash completion alias-aware.